# Problems with fgets function while multiple processes are running

Tags: c, process, fork, fgets

I'm not sure why but the fgets line is just skipped, when i paste the code that is run in child process 1.1 into a seperate file it works fine. I have read that it maybe an issue with the input buffer but I have no clue how to address this issue here

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int pid1, pid2, pid3, pid11, pid12, pid21, pid22;
    int n;
    char text[100];
    char input[100];

    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0) {
        // Child process 1
        if (creat("p1.txt", 0700) < 0) {
            printf("Error creating p1.txt\n ");
        }
        if (creat("p2.txt", 0700) < 0) {
            printf("Error creating p2.txt\n ");
        }

        pid11 = fork();
        if (pid11 == 0) {
            // Child process 1.1
                  printf("Enter your input: ");
                  fgets(input, 100, stdin);
                  printf("Your input: %s", input);

        } else {
            pid12 = fork();
            if (pid12 == 0) {
                // Child process 1.2
                
            }
            
        }
        wait(NULL);
    } else {
        pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 == 0) {
            // Child process 2
            pid21 = fork();
            if (pid21 == 0) {
                // Child process 2.1
                
            } else {
                pid22 = fork();
                if (pid22 == 0) {
                    // Child process 2.2
                    
                }
            }
            wait(NULL); // Wait for child process 2.1 to finish
        } else {
            pid3 = fork();
            if (pid3 == 0) {
                // Child process 3
                
            }
        }
    }

    wait(NULL); // Wait for all child processes to finish

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried also using printf but it doesn't work as well (I need to use fgets because my teacher said so). (The code isn't finished)

Comment: That's too ambiguous. What exactly is the problem here? What do you mean by "fgets() line is just skipped"?

Comment: The problem is that the fgets is not executed or maybe it just reads an EOF i have no clue, whenever I run the program the output looks like this "Enter your input: Your input:"and it doesnt wait for the user

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems (there are several) is in the wait() function.

Contrary to what you think, it only waits for one child at a time. So the whole program finishes early before you can enter anything.

if you replace `wait(NULL);` by `for(;;)wait(NULL);` the fgets will work as expected. (Note that adding an infinite loop is just for the demo; you should add several wait() at different places to wait for each child separately instead)

Answer (score 1):

J.P. Tosoni correctly named the cause of the failure, but didn't explain the interrelations, so I'll try.
It's actually not that *the fgets line is just skipped,* but rather the underlying `read` is executed with an error; if we inspect `errno` afterwards, we see `EIO`:

> I/O  error.  This will happen for example when the process is in a background process group, tries to read from its controlling terminal, and either it is ignoring or blocking SIGTTIN or its process group is orphaned.  It may also occur when there is a  low-level
> I/O error while reading from a disk or tape.

In the case at hand when the parent process exits, its process group (consisting of its children and grandchildren) becomes orphaned.